# How to stop a monitoring server form a parallel service?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have added a monitoring server, based on the [boost server3 example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.http_server_3). I have a parallel service that is running. I want to stop the server (or to change its output code) if some exception happens in the parallel service. Is that possible?

I have the following code in main function:

```
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
// ...

    // Register signal handlers so that the daemon may be shut down. You may
    // also want to register for other signals, such as SIGHUP to trigger a
    // re-read of a configuration file.
    boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    signals.async_wait(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::stop, &io_service));

    http::server::Server s("localhost", "5000");

    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&http::server::Server::run, &s));
    boost::thread t2(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));

    // Restore previous signals.
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &old_mask, 0);

    // Wait for signal indicating time to shut down.
    sigset_t wait_mask;
    sigemptyset(&wait_mask);
    sigaddset(&wait_mask, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&wait_mask, SIGQUIT);
    sigaddset(&wait_mask, SIGTERM);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &wait_mask, 0);
    int sig = 0;
    sigwait(&wait_mask, &sig);

    // Stop the server.
    s.stop();
    io_service.stop();
t.join();
    t2.join();
```

this is in a try catch block.

In io_service there are some exceptions that may happen, and if one has happen I want to change the output of the server. May I do that? How?

I thought of exceptions handling: rise a certain exception that, if happens, will stop the application. Is this the way to go, or is there another best practice?

If you think I have done something wrong in main, please correct me.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "parallel service"? Additional `asio::io_service`, dedicated to signal handlers? In a signal handler you could just `post()` some functor to the "primary" `io_service`, and that functor could raise an exception or just modify some internal `Server` state or so...

Comment: So what is wrong in doing `boost::thread t(boost::bind(&http::server::Server::run, &s));
    boost::thread t2(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));`? And how can I modify some internal Server state?